# PHP {$condition} && execute();

Tags: php, terminology

I've always used this code to run one line if statements.

```
$variable = TRUE; // or anything that evaluates to TRUE
$variable && execute_code();
```

Basically it would run the function if `$variable` is TRUE.

My question: 
What is the correct term for doing it this way?

Comment: me2, I used that in js, but doesn't seem to work so well in php...

Comment: Well, actually, it does work. At least in this context. My question is more on terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

> The short-circuit expression `x Sand y` (using Sand to denote the short-circuit variety) is equivalent to the conditional expression `if x then y else false;` the expression `x Sor y` is equivalent to `if x then true else y`.

Comment: This was killing me all day. Thank you!